# A level set of a smooth map, in which the rank is constant, but is not an embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Please provide examples of level sets of a smooth map between smooth manifolds such that the map has constant rank in the level set but the level set is not an embedded submanifold. As far as I know, if there is an open set which contains the level set and the map has constant rank there, the level set must be an embedded submanifold. Without such an open set, it may not be an embedded submanifold, but I can't imagine an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y) = x^2y^2$? At all points of the $0$-level set, the rank is $0$, but the level set is the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes, which is not an embedded submanifold.

If you want an example where the rank is constant but not zero, just add a dimension: Define $g\colon \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^2$ by $g(x,y,z) = (x^2 y^2,z)$. Then the $0$-level set is still the union of two axes, while the rank is $1$ at all points of the level set.

Comment: @lyrin: Sorry, I was too hasty. Think I fixed it now.